# Polymer typescript (ide) support

Tags: typescript, polymer, atom-editor, polymer-designer-tool

I'm interested in Polymer in combination with typescript. some good approaches have been discussed and seem to work nicely. My interest goes deeper:

- generate typescript definition files for the current polymer elements from the jsdoc (done)
- generate typescript classes from webcomponent html views so the views can be used in the polymer typescript webcomponent implemenations (this.$.).
- add support for the Atom editor (https://atom.io/) that also has good typescript support at this moment
- by using the above we can also provide autocompletion in Atom for both html views and typescript implementations at some level.

Question is: has the Google/Polymer team planned anything besides Chrome Dev Editor or Polymer designer (so an IDE with some typescript or other typed language support) like this or does this sound like useful project to put some work in?

Thanks in advance,

TypeScript webcomponents

Answer (score 0):

Polymer 2 will contain type defenitions and decorators.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/pull/3954

I'm trying to work out examples how to use them in vscode but they should work in atom too I guess.

https://github.com/gertcuykens/hello-world

https://github.com/gertcuykens/decorators